# how to get my deleted record again in its respective place

Tags: sql-server, ssis, powerbi

I have 24 records in source and target. I intentionally deleted id(pk) no.23 in the target and later if I rerun the SSIS package it was taking id no 25 instead of 23. I want id no.23 again in its place. What should I do
Thanks in advance

get my deleted record again in its respective place

Comment: Why is it so important that it keeps its value in the ID column? If it has to do with sortorders, use an additional column with the desired sortorder. You could set specific IDs by using [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) but identity columns aren't meant to be perceived to have any meaning (else than being a unique identifier).

Comment: An `IDENTITY` doesn't "fill in" the gaps when you `INSERT` new rows. If you `INSERT` 10 rows into a table with an `IDENTITY`, and then `DELETE` 5 of those rows the next value generated for the `IDENTITY` will still be `11`; it won't generate values for the "missing" numbers first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name, RESEED , new_reseed_value )
```

To reset the last value used before your error.

All increment tools (SEQUENCE, IDENTITY...) never returns lost values when a ROLLABCK or DELETE / TRUNCATE is done. You have to reset it maually with the specific MS SQL Server command.

Comment: i think this reseed will work for single row delete ,...suppose if i delete id no 2 ,5,12,23 ....then to restore again reseed works?

Comment: Reseed to the value you want. If you want to re inserts sparses id, you need to use SET INDENTITY_INSERT mytable ON / OFF

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add another ID column and use that in your selects. Before deleting, all of this would be duplicated from the identityID you are using now, 1/1 , 2/2, .... 24/24.

Then, if you delete 23 and insert again , maybe your original ID column will say "25", but you write logic to Insert "23" into the new column.